# Does not start session with KDE Plasma after updating

Tags: plasma5, antergos

When my system starts (ArchLinux - Antergos) the logging dialog appears and I enter my credentials, then it looks like my session would start but the logging dialog appears again.

So I am not able to start session with Plasma, however, via console, it's possible (by pressing CTR + ALT + F2), then I enter `plasmashell` to see the status and I get:

```
plasmashell: error while loading shared libraries: libKF5Auth.so.5 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That started occurring when I updated my system.

Where I can find it? or any alternative for this?

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/kauth/

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it to work.

I just downloaded the file: libKF5Auth.so.5 from [here](http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/linux/archlinux/extra/os/x86_64//kauth-5.52.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz).

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/fix-pacman-error-loading-shared-libraries-error-arch-linux/).

Basically, what it says is to put the file here:

```
cp libKF5Auth.so.5 /usr/lib/
```

Thanks @Ipor Sircer, I had no idea that the file kauth was the file plasma needed.